# Delete line breaks with an Apple wireless keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am really struggling with this.
On my old keyboard, I would position the cursor at the end of the text, go to the bottom of the page, hold down the del key on the numeric keyboard and the line breaks would delete before my eyes.
There is no numeric keypad on this keyboard and fn plus backspace doesn't take out the line breaks.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Delete removes content AFTER the cursor, backspace removes content BEFORE the cursor.

Ergo, Concordantly, Vis-a-vis...

Move your cursor to the top of the content that follows, and hit backspace until you remove the line break.